# NSURLConnection and beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

Tags: ios, multithreading, ipad, background, nsurlconnection

I'm using `NSURLConnection` to download archive 500mb. And I want to download it on background  thread, so I wrote:

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
self.theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
        self.backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            // Cancel the connection
            [self.theConnection cancel];
        }];
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTaskID];
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTaskID];
}
```

So if I did it on main thread it download and unarchive and working well, but if I start download and press `Home` button, so it start working on background thread it download 70% - 80% and it freezed. Method `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` don't call.

How can I download large file on background thread?

## Edit 1

I found that it called

```
self.backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            [self.theConnection cancel];
        }];
```

So connection finished, but I don't call `endBackgroundTask` in another methods.

Answer (score 1):

Apple allows your app run in background thread about 10 minutes (when you press home button).

NSURLSession is what you are looking for: [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> "This API provides a rich set of delegate methods for supporting authentication and gives your app the ability to perform background downloads when your app is not running or, in iOS, while your app is suspended."

Comment: `NSURLSession` available only in iOS 7.0, but I need to support iOS 6

Comment: I think that problem is in `App States and Multitasking`. How I can use method that available on `apple developer` `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`

Comment: >> background thread : You mean you press home and app runs background thread? If YES, I think your application will be killed in 10 minutes (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)    >>How can I download large file on background thread?  : At this time, in iOS 6, as I know, you cannot